# mvn command not found in eclipse but works on terminal

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven

mvn command not found in eclipse but works on mac terminal.
Where do I have to setup Path to Maven for eclipse. Tried articles from google but no luck.

Comment: Eclipse includes Maven. Please show us exactly what you did and which error you got. (Edit the question for that).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse includes an embedded version of maven. I suggest not to use it, but refer to the installed version in your environment. From eclipse -> windows -> preferences -> Maven -> Installations -> add: insert the path of your installed maven. Flag it. (not the embedded!).Then you can go to Maven -> User settings and enter the path to the settings.xml of your installed maven.
Then you can right click on the project -> maven -> update project or run as -> maven .. to execute tasks using the same maven installation of the terminal.